# How to partially update constant buffer in DirectX 11.1

Tags: c++, directx, game-engine

I am trying to partially update a constant buffer (as in opengl), but I always get weird errors, is there something I missed here as I just ported to DX11.1 for the Constant buffer partial update feature (also I support it and CBOffsetting)

```
void DX11UniformBuffer::Update(void * data, unsigned int offset, unsigned int size)
{
    const D3D11_BOX sDstBox = { offset, 0U, 0U, size, 1U, 1U };
    DX11Context::GetContext()->UpdateSubresource1(buffer, 0, &sDstBox, data, 0, 0,D3D11_COPY_DISCARD);
    DX11Context::GetContext()->PSSetConstantBuffers1(0, 1, &buffer, &offset, &size);
}
```

equivalent to (in opengl)

```
void GLUniformBuffer::Update(void * data, unsigned int offset, unsigned int size)
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, offset, size, data);
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

However I am getting these errors and nothing is drawn...

```
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::UpdateSubresource1: pDstBox is not a valid box, as the End coordinates must be greater than or equal to the Start. *pDstBox = { left:144, top:0, front:0, right:48, bottom:1, back:1 }. [ RESOURCE_MANIPULATION ERROR #288: UPDATESUBRESOURCE_INVALIDDESTINATIONBOX]
```

Answer (score 1):

The value for `right` in a `D3D11_BOX` is a *position*, not a *width*.  You need to add `offset` and `size` together to get the value for `right`.  `sDstBox` should be initialized as:

```
const D3D11_BOX sDstBox = { offset, 0U, 0U, offset + size, 1U, 1U };
```